# Symmetries of a Cube

Tags: geometry

Let $G$ be the group of rotational symmetries of a cube. Then $G\cong S_4$. Now $G$ acts on four diagonals of the cube.

> Prove that the only rotational symmetry of the cube which stabilizes four diagonals is the identity.

Here, a rotational symmetry stabilizes a diagonal means either it is leaving diagonal point-wise invariant, or it is flipping the diagonal at its midpoint.

---

Many resources (for example [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128170637/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65595.html)) show the isomorphism between $G$ and $S_4$ in the following way:

> $G$ acts on four diagonals of cube, hence giving a homomorphism $f\colon G\rightarrow S_4$. By orbit-stabilizer theorem, $|G|=24=|S_4$. If we show that $f$ is **surjective**, then it follows that $G\cong S_4$. ....

In my question, I want to see geometrically how the map $f\colon G\rightarrow S_4$ is **injective**, which is precisely the question posted. I came to this question by thinking the reverse way: whether we can show $f\colon G\rightarrow S_4$ injective (rather than surjective) in a geometric way.

Comment: I think people would like you to show that you have put some effort into this question, beyond that required to copy it from somewhere else into this website.

Comment: Any thoughts/questions about my answer?

Comment: Are you still here, Groups?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Our institute had some problem on internet. Your answer is very nice. I really have not copied this question. I have done the necessary changes in the question after your first comment, which may explain how I arrived at this natural question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v$ be a vertex of the cube. A rotational symmetry stabilizing the diagonals must either fix $v$ or take it to the vertex $v'$ diagonally opposite. Suppose it takes $v$ to $v'$.

Now consider the vertices $x,y,z$ adjacent to $v$. Each of these must be taken to a vertex adjacent to $v'$, but $x,y,z$ are not adjacent to $v'$, so each must be taken to the vertex diagonally opposite. So we see that any symmetry stabilizing the diagonals and not fixing $v$ must take every vertex to its diagonal opposite.

But such a symmetry can't be a rotational symmetry; it reverses orientation (it takes a right-handed coordinate system to a left-handed one). So, the only rotational symmetry fixing diagonals fixes all the vertices, and thus is the identity.